# Explain Ramsey sentences in simple terms

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science

Can you explain [Ramsey sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_sentences) in simple terms, maybe giving some concrete examples? I can't seem to understand them (everything about them),  no matter how hard I try.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you could speak more about what you _do_ and what you _do not_ understand about Ramsey sentences. As the wikipedia article you cited shows, an unfocused discussion of Ramsey sentences could go on for a long time -- unreasonably long for an answer on this forum. What do you get, and what don't you get?

Comment: @senderle, you can explain a lot of complicated and broad things in a few paragraphs with a few concrete examples. I've already stated that I don't understand _anything_ about Ramsey sentences - related literature is way over my head, too.

Comment: Ah, well the way you phrased the question made it sound like you _do_ get some things and not others. If you literally understand _nothing_ about them, then I would recommend reading some basic background material on the history of positivism, and concepts like observable and unobservable entities, scientific realism, anti-realism, and empiricism. IMO, it will be difficult to motivate or explain them without assuming that background knowledge. (And If you understand some of those things, then you _do_ understand some things about Ramsey sentences, even if you don't realize it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.jimpryor.net/teaching/courses/mind/notes/ramseylewis.html) website from philosopher Jim Pryor has a nice illustration of the importance and use of Ramsey sentences, and uses the example of the parts of a car.

Answer (score -1):

This is a self-referencing question, as it would take several Ramsey sentences to break down how Ramsey sentences work for someone who knows nothing about them to explain the concept of Ramsey sentences. I can't believe nobody saw that.